# Can a custom command be placed in attribute table window toolbar in ArcMap?

Tags: arcobjects, gui

Is it possible to place custom command on ArcMap's attribute table window toolbar? As far as I understand I need GUID or ProgID of this toolbar in order to find appropriate **ICommandItem** with **ICommandBars.Find** method. But I cannot find this ID.